# Как сделать необычное выпадающее мегаменю?

Tags: html, css

пожалуйста, помогите решить нестандартную задачку.

**ЧТО ИМЕЕМ:** Есть обычное верхнее, горизонтальное меню с подменю, оно лежит в рабочей области сайта равной 1000px по ширине, но засада в том, что нужно чтобы при клике на любой пункт меню, выпадали сразу все подменю, но, разная высота блоков подменю делает некрасивым общий вид подменю. Сами блоки подменю в position absolute сейчас. Это важно. fixed верхнего не годиться.

**ВОПРОС:** как средствами CSS (без js) сделать заливку-подложку фон, под эти все блоки подменю? Учитывая их высоту, которая неизвестна, высота по контенту. И ширина подложки не должна ограничиваться рабочей областью сайта, в котором лежит все меню. Не мог понять как это сделать :( пробовал псевдоэлементами, но они ограничиваются шириной рабочей области меню. В общем не хватает ума это провернуть.

Что есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот живой пример

```js
  //top-nav
  $('.mega-menu').on('click', '.top-list__item > a', function () {
    $('.mega-menu').find('.top-list__item__link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    if ($('.header__menu').hasClass('open')) {
      $('.header__menu').removeClass('open');
    } else {
      $('.header__menu').addClass('open');
    }
  });
```

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style: none;
}
.container{
max-width:1000px;
 width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.mega-menu{
  width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
}
.header__menu {
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
.top-list__item{
  flex:1;
  width:100%;
}
.top-list__item a{
  color:#fff;
      padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.header__menu, .mega-menu {
    position: relative;
}
.top-list__sublist {
    display: none;
        top: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 54px;
  padding-right: 30px;
      position: absolute;
    background: #333;
}
.open .top-list__sublist {
    display: block;
}
.top-list__sublist a{
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header__menu">
<div class="mega-menu flex-container">
    <ul class="top-list flex-container">
        <li class="top-list__item">
            <a href="#">1 пункт</a>
            <ul class="top-list__sublist">
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   
           <li class="top-list__item">
               <a href="#">2 пункт</a>
            <ul class="top-list__sublist">
                 <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   
           <li class="top-list__item">
               <a href="#">3 пункт</a>
            <ul class="top-list__sublist">
                 <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     
           <li class="top-list__item">
                   <a href="#">4 пункт</a>
            <ul class="top-list__sublist">
                 <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   
           <li class="top-list__item">
               <a href="#">5 пункт</a>
            <ul class="top-list__sublist">
                 <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Присваивайте `position: absolute` не для `.top-list__sublist`, а для всего `.header__menu`, при клике у вас будут отображаться или скрываться `.top-list__sublist`.

```js
$(".top-list__item").click(() => {
    $('.sublist').toggleClass('sublist-showed')
  })
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container,
.mega-menu {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #333
}

.mega-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.top-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}


.top-list:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}

.top-list__link {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.top-list__link,
.sublist__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.sublist {
  display: none;
}

.sublist-showed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="mega-menu">
    <ul class="top-list">
      <li class="top-list__item">
        <a class="top-list__link" href="#">1 пункт</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="top-list__item">
        <a class="top-list__link" href="#">2 пункт</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="top-list__item">
        <a class="top-list__link" href="#">3 пункт</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="top-list__item">
        <a class="top-list__link" href="#">4 пункт</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="top-list__item">
        <a class="top-list__link" href="#">5 пункт</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
          <li><a class="sublist__link" href="#">подпунк мегаменю</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
    Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
    годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
    Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
    годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так на всю ширину растянуть??? Это основная проблема :( Я перепробовал почти все, и псевдоэлементы с отрицательными значениями, но они рвут дизайн несмотря на абсолютную позицию.

Comment: поправил. Для .header__menu надо добавить width: 100%, left: 0

Comment: ой, забыл указать, при условии что само меню находиться в position:relative

Comment: @Cheizer вы уверены, что вам надо все подпункты открывать, а не тот на который нажали?

Comment: да вот в том то и дело, что все сразу нужно

Comment: Дополнил, но менюшка ваша не юзабельна, т.к. вы 5 разными кнопками выполняете одинаковое действие - раскрываете полное меню, смысла в этом нет никакого, юзабельности и понятности в ваше меню это не добавит. В вашей хотелке логичней вынести всё подменю (sublist) в отдельный блок.

Comment: Вы бесконечно правы! ДА, все так, но задумка такая, открывать все надо, и задумка не моя, НО ДЕЛО В ТОМ, что не могу вынести в отдельный блок потому, ПЕРВАЯ ПРИЧИНА  нужна одинаковая ширина верхних пунктов меню, и колонок подменю, и ВТОРАЯ ПРИЧИНА на мобиле меню становиться обычным, вертикальным с подпунктами. Вот как быть?

Comment: @Cheizer Вам же надо создать просто видимость того, что сабменю относится к панели навигации, вы можете это все реализовать двумя отдельными элементами. 1 - меню, которое в header. 2 - Модальное окно, повторяет кнопки меню из Header и имеет субменю. На мобиле вы просто скрываете меню N1 и по кнопке бургера отображаете только адаптированное модальное окно N2

Comment: Это понятно что можно разделить, но что бы сделать видимость что сабменю относиться к верхнему меню, нужна одинаковая ширина субменю, равная пунктам верхнего меню, тут начинаются проблемы и наращивание JS